# Condition based on a page existence in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a multilingual docs site for OSS built with Jekyll `3.8.5`.

Currently, all items in the global navigation link to English pages.

I want to improve the global navs to contain URL to translated page if exists, otherwise English page as fallback. Since not all pages are translated.

Page structure is like below.

```
* _collection1
    * page1.md
    * page2.md
* _es
    * collection1
        * page1.md
* _ja
    * collection1
        * page2.md
* _fr
   :
```

My attempted strategy is below.

1. Construct and capture `translatedPageId` to be tested.
2. Find the page by `translatedPageId`.
3. If the page found, generate a link to the translated page.
   Otherwise generate a link to the English page.

Jekyll code is something like below. Suppose `page` have a `language` property to indicate current page language (e.g. `es`, `fr`, `ja` or etc).

```
{% capture translatedPageId %}/{{page.language}}{{navItem.url | remove_first: '.html' }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign translatedPage = site.pages | where: 'id', translatedPageId | first %}
<a {% if translatedPage.url %}
      href="{{ translatedPage.url }}
   {% else %}
      href="{{ englishPage.url }}
   {% endif %}
>...</a>
```

Expected: `translatedPage` is assigned and `translatedPage.url` should be non empty.

Actual: `translatedPage` is `nil` and `translatedPage.url` is `nil` too.
It looks like Jekyll does not allow filter (`where`) by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `site.pages` do not contain pages in `collection`.
To find pages in `collection`, it is required to use `site.documents` instead.